# How to stop mysql table select query for any application user except one?

Tags: mysql, transactions, cakephp-1.2

I know that my question is related to transactions or tables lock, but I could not able to manage it. My PHP application has to select some values from a table then it has to loop through the results to update some values in the same result.
I want the application to stop any user select when there is a select query is operating till the loop is completed.

I used lock tables write, but it prevented the application to do the update.
My application is built on CakePHP 1.2.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something is wrong because your script should be able to UPDATE data on the table while it is WRITE locked for the users, check this URL and I hope it would help.
[When and how to lock tables](http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/php/php_mysql/When_and_how_to_lock_tables.html)

Comment: Stackoverflow does not inform me about the answer!